# Silverlight App cannot access a resource namespace from the Domain Service Project

Tags: silverlight

Hi I have a silverlight application which has the following project structure:

**Solution**
|-------Project1.App  (this is the Silverlight Application Project)
|
|-------Project1.App.Service.Web (this is the Domain Service Project)
|
|-------Project1.App.Web (this is the Website Project)

`Project1.App.Web` has a reference to the `Project1.App.Services.Web`  and `Project1.App` has a reference through RIA WCF reference (Silverlight Project Settings) to the `Project1.App.Web`

The problem comes when I am trying to access one of the name spaces in the resource files in the `Project1.App.Services.Web`
The Resource Designer.CS of the `Project1.App.Services.Web` looks like this:

```
Namespace Project1.App.Resources.Server {
    using System;


    /// <summary>
    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    /// </summary>
   // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
   // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
   // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
   // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
public class BatchTypeResources {
```

now in one of the shared classes from the `Project1.App.Services.Web` project  with the silverlight project

```
using Project1.App.Resources.Server;
```

and I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Server' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Project1.App.Resources' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\DEV\App\Source\Platform
>   Development\Project1.App\Project1.App\Generated_Code\Project1.App.Services.Web\Models\Shared\CustomValidations.shared.cs

Keep in mind that if I go to the `Project1.App.Services.Web` project  and to that class the project compiles without issues; it is the Silverlight Project that fails to compiled.

The resources files are hosted in the `Project1.App.Services.Web` projects and they were added to the silverlight Project as linked files.

Any ideas why is this failing?

Comment: are you trying to reference a .net assembly in silverlight?

Comment: yes i am the .net class is the domain services